# Informix Docker Container won’t restart after -stop (from CL) or pause (from Desktop). Must re-initialize each time

Tags: docker, containers, informix

I am wondering if my instance of Informix Dev Edition (each time, latest, currently as of 4/2/2023) is not re-starting because of not a binding issue (I’m not), —-privileged flag (I don’t think so), not attaching via outside terminal (I run docker exec properly each time and it works perfectly until I have to stop Informix). I have to docker run each time, I can’t restart it. When I try to start it shuts down very quickly. There are many KAIO errors and it won’t reinitialize shared memory.
docker run -it --name iif_developer_edition --privileged -p 9088:9088 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest

What I think is going on is the version I keep pulling somehow is the Linux/AMD64 and not ARM. I have a MacBook Pro M1 (new, refurbished) which is fine otherwise. I think I need to somehow force the issue and tell Docker to pull it as the ARM version as the Docker Desktop has warnings about instability or not running, but it runs everything fine, never crashes, it just won’t stop in a way that I am not forced to do docker run each time. Thank you

Please see above. I have to docker run -it --name iif_developer_edition --privileged -p 9088:9088 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest each time after I close or exit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't recall any 'recent' ARM Informix docker image (at least not one built by Informix).
The new images (latest is 14.10.FC9W1) are now in the IBM Container Registry (icr.io) as Informix is moving way to host images in docker.hub.  Check out the project page at https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme.   
I ran a quick "docker run, docker exec, docker stop, docker run, docker exec" test on my linux box and latest FC9W1 image was working as expected.  Maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no recent **as-indicated** ARM images for Informix Developer Edition. Correct.
2. When i do a `docker run --latest`, the container that shows up in Docker is "flagged" in a little box which says AMD64 and notes when hovered that it may be unstable or not run.
3. I agree that running it on a Linux box would reveal no issues.

   I believe that this issue has not been covered well but is has in fact been addressed elsewhere and [here](https://bornsql.ca/blog/you-can-run-a-sql-server-docker-container-on-apple-m1-and-m2-silicon/) . Apparently, Informix may need to be run in emulation, as indicated in [1](https://bornsql.ca/blog/you-can-run-a-sql-server-docker-container-on-apple-m1-and-m2-silicon/), by an option within Docker, `Find the Features in development` option, and select the `Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon` checkbox.
4. If you believe that this is the issue I am having, please let me know. I will be working on this and report back. Ideally, I would run this on a Linux box!
   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The options in Docker worked! The container still says I am running an AMD 64 container but I can re-start the container w/o deleting it and doing a new pull/run, re-starting works and the log reveals no unusual differences from a normal start, no disk-space re-initializing required.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyVxQ.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWlZQ.jpg)

Comment: You can edit your answers.  You should probably add this information to your first answer (or vice versa) and delete this (or the other).